# Put filters and sorting to separate blocks into Drupal 9 Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views, drupal-9

I am regularly working on Drupal projects where Views lists are involved. The possibility to put filters into a block and place them at a dedicated place into my layout is great but not enough.

Indeed, the most part of time, the designers which I am working with are creating layouts where filters and sorts are not placed in the same block. And the separate blocks are placed at different places of the layout.

One way to fix it is to replicate sorting part with JS and creating a clone of original dropdown location. But I am sure that there could be a best way to achieve that goal.

Someone do know how to split dropdown lists into two blocks from PHP hooks or custom overriding module ?